# How do I improve my question?

Tags: discussion, support, unclear

My question, *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657417*, has been put on hold because:

> As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please help me re-phrase my question so as the hold may be lifted from it.

Comment: To me the question looks more like a mathematics problem, rather than a programming one. And you have already answered it in the question, so what's the point of reopening it?

Comment: I would even take into considerstion if it is even on-topic here? Maybe it fits better on [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/)? Or one of the CS sites...

Comment: If you are going to self-answer questions in the future, make sure you ask the question in a way that will be answerable by people other than you, then post your answer as an answer, not as the body of the question. We hold self-answered questions to the same standards as all other questions. Same goes for the answer you provide to your own question.

Comment: @gnat -- Sir, I don’t know whether to thank you for your editing my post. On one hand, you turned the respectful tone of my post into a sycophantic one. On the other hand, the post is racking up plus votes. :-)

Comment: @user1360434 the respectfulness is unnecessary noise and because tone can be lost in writing, being overly respectful as you were, can come off sarcastic and condescending.  The best way to be respectful on Stack Overflow is to ask well written questions without the fluff.

Comment: @psubsee2003 -- While I have you, as it were, on the phone, is there a way for me delete my account?

Comment: @user1360434 http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account.  Although before deleting your account, you way want to wait for a few day to let the dust settle from your issue today.  Once it gets deleted, you can't undo it.  You may find that after a few days, you will feel differently.  You have not even received much feedback on your question yet.

Comment: _"I'm, for some reason, unable to delete this post."_ That's because there is an upvoted answer. You can only self-delete your questions if (a) there is no answer or (b) there is only one answer with a score of zero or less.

Comment: Also worth noting, you do not need "Edit" or a time stamp in your post itself to denote an edit. That is already noted in the edit history, which you can see by clicking the little link that says "edited x ago" just below your question. "Edit" is considered unnecessary fluff in questions due to the link to the revision history.

Comment: And to add to @Kendra comment on your edit - you can't really "close" a question in the sense you want to with your comments.  Whether or not you are interested in the answers or further discussion, other users may be interested in the discussion or the contents of the post.  However, if you really feel that there is little value to leaving this post, you can click the "flag" link under your question, click "Other" and explain briefly why you would like the question deleted.

Comment: @user1360434, Just by the way, awesome job at rephrasing your MSE post. This is exactly the right thing to do, and the right place to do it. Well done. I hope you can also see, of course, how this approach is a fair bit more effective, too :).

Comment: Don't announce in the question that the issue is solved (and you don't need to put bold "edit" marks). Instead either accept one of existing answers, or put your own answer and accept it - this is a common way of indicating that the problem is solved.

Comment: You were helped by people that aren't male... it's a bit rude to only thank the "gentlemen". Just saying.

Comment: @BartoszKP -- With all respect to you, you don't seem to be familiar with the issue I faced. Moderators suspended my question. Hence, nobody, including myself, could answer my question. Forty hours later, I finally found the answer, having read hundreds of pages. The underlying problem of my question and solution to it is non-trivial. I thought future generations of readers might find my discovery useful. That's all.

Comment: @eddie_cat -- I corrected my form of address.

Comment: @user1360434 (are we talking about the same question? - I'm referring to *this* meta question). The way that SO and MSO work is that you put questions in questions and answers in answers. As simple as that :) Mixing these two causes unnecessary mess. I understand that perhaps you were unable to answer the question, but now you can, so please consider putting things in order - thanks! :)

Answer (score 14):

How about you try reading these articles about how to write a good and perfect question:

[Jon Skeet's How to Write the Perfect Question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) 
[How to Write a Good Question From The Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
[Writing A Question The Smart Way by Eric S. Raymond](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) 
[Getting Answers by Mike Ash](https://mikeash.com/getting_answers.html)

These articles have proven useful for those Stack Overflow newbies or people who get question bans. The first one is written by the number one ranked user in terms of reputation. The Help Center is great place to visit (second link). The other two are very precise and easy to read but long.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Because you provided a valid, well written answer that helped someone....

Comment: Perhaps because it's a links-only answer. They share the same drawback as on the main site - links rot.

Comment: @BartoszKP and yet, sometimes resummarizing one or many articles into an Answer isn't viable.  This is one of the more controversial basis for a downvote, I think

Comment: @NewAlexandria These links can be easily put into a comment, and I don't believe that they cannot be summarized, at least separately. And even if it's not viable (I don't know for what reason that could be the case here though), this does not invalidate the policy on link-only answers, that makes sense and should be followed.

Comment: These links may have been summarize-able, but others may not very easily.  I agree that those are, still, low-quality answers.  If it's the only answer, I think that's a challenge.  If OP doesn't want to edit / summarize, then I think that anyone else is game for learning from said links and writing a better answer themselves — which in a meritocracy will receive more upvotes.

Comment: @NewAlexandria Of course anyone is always welcome to provide a better answer. But it doesn't change a thing about quality of this answer.