# How to improve questions to make them easier to comprehend?

Tags: support, asking-questions, code-formatting, stack-snippets

I have recently been asking questions, and struggling to make my questions easier to read without hurting people's eyes or drawing their attention away from key elements. I don't want to have to flood the comments with answers to their questions on formatting, and they are usually different.

My question is, how do I effectively format my questions to make them easier to comprehend, and easy on the eyes? Does the title effect the question regarding the point of confusion?

I have a question **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336267/urgent-js-typing-animation-not-working-suddenly)** I was trying to get answered, but even after my attempts at making it easier to comprehend, people were still having questions about my wording and placement of resources.

**References**:

[When should I elaborate answers to make them better?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299523/when-should-i-elaborate-answers-to-make-them-better)

[How do I improve my question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281483/how-do-i-improve-my-question)

Comment: Side note, pls don't [SOLVED] in a title.  Add an answer and select it, if other answers didn't solve it for you.  I think the main problem about your question was you were asking for others to debug your code for you.  If you did debug it, you should have included your findings in the question so others wouldn't have to do it for you.  Making sure you're not wasting the time of folks who are donating theirs to help you, free of charge, is really important.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have two suggestions to offer. Both involve putting psychological distance between yourself and the question. That distance gives you a valuable perspective on how other people will view and understand what you've written.

First, get someone else, possibly multiple someones, to read the post over for you. Ask them if they understand what you're writing about. Ask them if anything's unclear, distracting, under- or over-specified. Obviously this will be most helpful if you have someone with a little technical knowledge and maybe some experience on the site, but even without that you may get some good basic critique.

Second, *don't post the question immediately after writing it*. Write it out, check it over, and then put it aside, for an absolute minimum of an hour. Overnight is even better, and if you have the luxury of reviewing it a few times over the course of days, do that. For that hour, *do something else*. Get your head out of that problem space. You will be amazed at the things you see when you come back to it with a different frame of mind. I'm sure you've experienced this with a troublesome bit of code; it's true of prose as well.

When you return, your headspace will be a little more similar to the state that other people are seeing the question in, and that will help you get some inkling of what they might think.

Comment: This is absolutely perfect advice, and something that surprisingly few people seem to have an intuitive grasp of. It would be nice if we could somehow get this advice in front of new users, especially new users who appear to be *trying* but not having good luck in asking questions. The only thing I would possibly add here is that, if you don't have anyone else that you can ask or that is willing to listen, it can often be just as helpful to read the post out loud and explain it to no one in particular (after waiting a while, of course). This is basically rubber duck debugging. A pet will do.

Comment: I also find that taking some time away from the question and then returning to it allows me to solve my problem without asking it. I try to follow the notion of "asking on Stack Overflow should be one of the last resorts on the planet for your programming question"; in other words, really punish myself mentally if I haven't spent days trying to solve my issue already.

Answer (score 7):

You should post the smallest amount of code that reproduces the problem you're having. You should also start the question with your problem statement.

As it stands, opening your question results in being bombarded by an enormous code block that requires extensive scrolling before even seeing what the problem is. I'm guessing this top code block is the library you're using, you probably don't need to post that in this case. If you're posting it for the snippet to work, put it at the bottom and maybe choose to start with the snippet closed to make the question look smaller.

You're then posting *more* code and then asking a very open ended question (how do I implement this?)

Try and reduce the amount of code you're posting to what is relevant to your problem, utilize websites like JSFiddle for your entire code to demonstrate the problem, and ask a concise about a specific issue you are having.

Comment: So I'll have to present the problem first, and have an organized list of resources on external sites? Is there a way to collapse a JS fiddle to a button?

Comment: @CodyBennett the Stack Overflow snippets have an option to hide by default. If you're posting a large amount of code or links to other resources, you should probably reconsider the question you're asking, or ask the question on the library's support area.