# Why was my question about restarting SQL server closed and downvoted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Despite [demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49362765/sql-server-wont-stop) efforts to solve the problem on one's own, demonstrated effort to independently search for a resolution as well as evidence of no current posts/questions on SO, one can still be downvoted repeatedly and have one's questions paused.  If the question is clear and evidence for effort, research and duplication avoidance posted is still not enough, then what is to be the hurdle?  Perhaps SO is only for Computer Science majors.

[image: Screenshot of question]

Comment: What does stopping SQL server have to do with programming? Why would this question not be better suited for Server Fault or Super User?

Comment: There are sql-server tags & questions, but aside from that fact databases are critical to many programs/websites.

Comment: In the same way that your operating system, computer hardware, chair and desk are critical. Again, there are specific sites like Server Fault and Super User. Why would this question not be a better fit on those sites?

Comment: Indeed, but that doesn't make the question programming-related or oriented. Even if you avoid duplication, research intensively, and make your question clear, a question about cooking should be downvoted/closed.

Comment: Agree with @Patrice. Your own screen shot shows that you didn't even include all of the necessary information in the question and had to add it as a comment.

Comment: You don't need a chair or desk to access a website but without a database its not much of a website.  Then remove the sql-server tag as it's a topic for other sites.  And there are plenty of other examples where questions have demonstrated effort, research and are clear which still receive the same treatment.

Comment: Again, my question about can be well researched and all... how does cooking have to do with Stack? And there can be **programming** questions related to sql-server, so the tag should stay. The fact there is a tag for "java" doesn't mean I can start asking about coffee.... Just like sql-server means that the tag is valid, if the question relates to sql-server and is a programming question.

Comment: You don't need a database to have a website either, you can simply have a static html page

Comment: @Patrice my comments provide no data that my question did not.  Stop doesn't work.  & There are no tags for cooking.  It's a snarky comment.  Those new to the site can see that there are tags for that topic, being able to ask questions is logical.  Also there are tags for AutoCAD which have nothing to do with programming at all.

Comment: @Wayne I'm making an argument by pushing your own argument to the extreme to show you where your logic fails. See it as snarky if you want, but  it's how the system works (and how I've chosen to express that fact).  I never said ANYTHING about your comments here, so I don't know how this comes in the mix now. I am not saying the move you did isn't a logical move. It doesn't mean it's the correct one though, which is what we're telling you here.  And your last point about AutoCAD... ok... how does the fact "other tags are worse" means this is okay?

Comment: If you see other off topic content, flag as such. Don’t use it as an excuse for posting your own. Managing daemons/server software isn’t really a programming problem, which is why the other sites exist. Why is posting your question on a site dedicated to the thing you’re asking about a problem for you?

Comment: When there are tags for items and you've written a clear question and posted your work, one could simply point out where go or close the question.  But downvoting a new user who is making legitimate effort services no real purpose.  By posting my problem here I have learned of other place I can go.

Comment: Not without arguing against it, though. Seems pointless.

Comment: Oh, so we're back at "please justify your downvotes"? or "please don't downvote newbies"? or some other such question? Then we are in the "very well duplicated at this point" territory.  Downvoting serves a purpose: quality control, the very reason you turn to this site instead of going to Yahoo Answers.

Comment: see also: [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677/839601)

Comment: Apologies for wasting ppls time, no intent to upset, offend or argue was purposed.  I should have clarified by stating my inflection.  I value the time of all of those who make time to help others.  Thank you.  I will direct my questions to the other sites.  Thank you for listing them.  I am happy to delete this post, but in my humble opinion I think it may provide some clarity to those find themselves in a similar place as I did today.  I need to resolve my sql situation.

Comment: _"trying to learn why it was deemed off topic"_ Your Meta title really started things off in a different direction than this, and even the body is more complaint than query. You might do well to edit some more. And/or [wait a bit before posting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337330) next time.

Comment: I don't understand in your SO question that you say your SO search didn't return results  because those searches return [either 723](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=can%27t+stop+SQL+Server&mixed=0) or [24 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SQL+Server+wont+stop+&mixed=0). Can you verify that the search is working for you as intended and if it did what *no results* mean? I hope it does mean you tried all 747 posts and not a single one solved your problem, nor did they reveal any new or additional information that could provide extra context for your specific issue.

Comment: Reverted question so that the answers and comments are relavant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, a lot of the comments here are crap - SQL Server questions are fine, as long as they're related to developing with SQL Server (a very common task) vs. administering a production server (also a common task, but one better suited for our [Database Administrators site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)).

Fortunately, your question wasn't *closed* as off-topic; rather, unclear.

This is the bit a LOT of folks struggle with. You've tried all sorts of things, and none of them have worked. There must be something you're missing, but it can't be the things you've already tried, right!

...Except, we don't know what you tried. Or what you might've missed while trying them. The symptoms you've listed are... Nothing - of course, right, that's the whole point of frustration, *nothing is happening...*

So... This is one of those times when you probably have to provide a lot more information than you think is relevant, simply because you're at a point where nothing obviously relevant has helped!

You say you followed the instructions on the MS site, and I'm sure you did. But perhaps there's a clue among them as to what went wrong, something you didn't expect or overlooked? This is *precisely* where more eyeballs can help: a co-worker standing over your shoulder asking questions as you go along. Or... A bunch of folks on Stack Overflow. Except, we can't see over your shoulder; you'd have to provide us with details on what you saw / did at each step of the process.

Sounds tedious, right? But... What else can we do here? If I follow [those instructions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/start-stop-pause-resume-restart-sql-server-services) and SQL Server services stop just fine... What can I tell you? "It works on my machine" isn't very helpful either.

Comment: With this post, I learned of other forums for Administrative SQL-Server questions. On those other forums, I learned that when IT installed SQL Server Express, they used their credentials and assigned me no permissions. Problem solved. Many of the comments on this post, while I can understand their origin, provide no real value to SO or to myself. Many on SO who love coding and this forum have grown unable to communicate to those who need more help. I listened and took the steps I was given. And it helped me solve the issue. Like the plurality of new OS users, I will not return.

Answer (score -6):

The message for closure tells you what needed to be done.

You were asked to provide additional information, and instead of editing it into the question, you posted it as a comment.

Edit the question, it will go into the reopen queue, and it might be reopened.

Comment: No it won't. It is off topic.

Comment: then it should have been closed for that reason.

Comment: Meh @sevenseacat, doesn’t really matter. Off topic is off topic, plus it was actually unclear what was being asked so technically the given reason is accurate

Comment: @Clive I think the point, and it makes sense, is that "unclear" sends a signal of "improve your question, then it will be okay". If it's truly off-topic, the "off-topic, should go to this site instead" is more unequivocal as to what the next step should be.

Comment: Yeah @Patrice, but don’t migrate (or redirect) crap, right?

Comment: @Clive indeed.... then the question would be how to send both signals clearly to the user, so that they can get their question clarified AND migrated....

Comment: Yeah that would be more useful @Patrice. If anyone manages to squeeze that all seamlessly into SO’s normal workflow I think a nobel prize would be in order...